# DHCP reservations for a range of MAC addresses

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, dhcp

**Question**

Our DHCP server is set up to only give IP addresses to machines that it knows about (all IPs excluded, reservations for each MAC address). Part of the address range is used for virtual machines on a Hyper-V cluster, managed by Microsoft System Center.

Currently, the virtual machines get MAC addresses from an address pool, and there are DHCP reservations for the first addresses in that pool. The problem is that virtual machines are regularly being added and removed, and a couple days ago, those reservations ran out. I had to figure out what addresses were still being used, clean up unused reservations, and create new ones for the next set of MAC addresses.

Is there a way to reserve a set of addresses by prefix? Is there some feature I don't know about, or a feature with a higher domain functional level? We can raise the level if needed (currently 2008, but our servers are 2012 and 2012 R2).

**Information**

- Domain functional level: Windows Server 2008
- Microsoft System Center 2012 R2

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating static reservations, why not set mac restrictions to get a normal DHCP address?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff521761.aspx

> MAC address filtering (aka link-layer filtering) is a feature for IPv4
>   addresses that allows you to include or exclude computers and devices
>   based on their MAC address.

[image]

Comment: Will this work in combination with the reservations for the rest of the network? These machines are on the same subnet as everything else, which is managed by DHCP reservations.

Comment: I'm not sure what your current reservations are...but you could add multiple "Allow these mac addresses" filters to include any/all of your mac addresses.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Machines need to keep their reserved addresses because a) they're not always in DNS and b) certain ranges are used for certain things (50-99 faculty, 200-240 lab, etc.). That solution sounds like I'd have to maintain two sets of MAC addresses (one in the filter list and one in the reservations).

Comment: Nope, you can have reservations within the scope as well.  But I'm saying ALL macs need to be accounted for in the filter.  If your DHCP servers were 2012 R2 then you could do per scope filtering instead.  But if you only have a single scope now, then that's irrelevant.  You'll want to make sure ALL mac addresses within your org (by wildcard) are accounted for in the allow list filter.  Reservations are after that within the scope itself and still allowed.

Comment: We can't wildcard everyone in because we need to only allow specific devices. Otherwise anyone could plug in a computer into a network jack and get an IP address. That's what the reservations currently do - every address is excluded, so the only computers that get an address are the ones that have reservations. (This also ensures that a machine always keeps the same IP.) So what I need is a way to assign a subset of that range (100-199) to VMs, while still preventing any other machine from hopping in there.

Comment: @stephenwade Then there is no way to do the ridiculous thing you want, in the ridiculous way you want it done.  Someone much more motivated and better paid than myself could probably script something up for you, but as I'm neither motivated, nor being paid, I'm only willing to point you in the direction of the DHCP PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: I never said to wildcard everyone.  You already lock down by mac via reservation...so why can't you lock down by filter instead using a wildcard reservation for just the VM "mac pool" and putting in additional filters based on the current other mac addresses you allow?  I'm not sure where your security focus is...if you are concerned about port/network security you should look at implementing 802.1X along with port learning if that's the ultimate concern here...otherwise the DHCP scope filters is the way to go.

Comment: @TheCleaner The reason I don't want to do that is because every time we added a device, I'd have to add it in two places – the filter and the reservation

Comment: You don't know ahead of time the range of mac addresses so that you can setup the filter once?  If that's the case and you are bringing in new mac addresses all the time then the only solution is manually entering each reservation.  You understand though that if you aren't using port-based-security there's nothing stopping someone with an unknown mac from statically assigning themselves an IP and getting on the network?

Comment: I know the range for the VMs, but not new faculty laptops, etc. But that's a good point about just self-assigning a static IP. I'll bring that up to my advisor.